# Error using Hashtable for windows phone application

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-7

I want to use this [expression parser](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/patricklundin/MathExpParser12062005062213AM/MathExpParser.aspx).

I import this code that is on the site:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using info.lundin.Math;
// some other imports

public class Test 
{
  public static void Main( String[] args )
  {
    // Instantiate the parser
    ExpressionParser parser = new ExpressionParser();
    // Create a hashtable to hold values
    Hashtable h = new Hashtable();
    // Add variables and values to hashtable
    h.Add( "x", 1.ToString() );
    h.Add( "y", 2.ToString() );
    // Parse and write the result
    double result = parser.Parse( "xcos(y)", h );
  }
}
```

but it says that the namespace Hashtable could not be found.
i google it and i found out that Hashtables are not included in Silverlight and  i should use a dictionary.

But when i use dictionary it gives my an error that says:
cannot convert from `System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,string>` to `System.Collections.Hashtable`

Any suggestions?

Comment: You should upgrade the parser to use a dictionary instead.

Comment: What's the code look like that gives you the "cannot convert from System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary to System.Collections.Hashtable" error?

Answer (score 2):

I would modify the source code in the parser program so that it also is compatible with Silverlight(i.e. change any hashtable implementations into dictionary implementations)

Answer (score 0):

Hashtables and ArrayLists are not included in the silverlight. So you cant use it.

You can use generic collections—List and Dictionary instead of HashTables and ArrayLists.